# matplotlib basemap and cross section of hypocenters

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap

I managed to plot epicentres (from a: latitude, longitude, depth, magnitude file)  on a 2D XY map, but I can not find a way to make a cross section of them. (Meaning select an azimuth and a width range, and plot the hypocenters on a xz plot).

GMT has the ability to do such cross-sections, using projection, like described here:
http://mygeologypage.ucdavis.edu/gps/GMT/LONG_VALLEY/hypocenter.html

Any ideas on how it could be done?

Sample alike to what I did so far:

```
import requests
from csv import DictReader 
DATA_URL='http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/4.5_month.csv'
print("Downloading", DATA_URL)
resp = requests.get(DATA_URL)
quakes = list(DictReader(resp.text.splitlines()))

lngs = [float(q['longitude']) for q in quakes]
lats = [float(q['latitude']) for q in quakes]
depths=[float(q['depth']) for q in quakes]
mags = [2 ** float(q['mag']) for q in quakes]

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
plt.figure(figsize=(14, 8))
earth = Basemap()
earth.bluemarble(alpha=0.42)
earth.drawcoastlines(color='#555566', linewidth=1)  
plt.scatter(lngs, lats, mags, 
            c='red',alpha=0.5, zorder=10)
```

Comment: I guess this is not so much about plotting than about getting the correct data? (Because once you have the data, you can just `plt.plot(x,z)`.)

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest well you need to make an azimuthal selection/projection because the cross section has a direction and a width

Comment: Yes, but you would need to do it on the data, not on the plot.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Yes the actual "job" needs to be done on the data. On the plot only the line of the cross section , with its width needs to be plotted.